# Запуск python-скрипта через терминал

Tags: python, terminal

Добрый вечер. Как передать скрипту на питоне имя файла через терминал, не используя input? 
Т.е. мне нужно добиться примерно следующего:

```
$ python pprint.py filename.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import sys

file_name = sys.argv[1]
```

Comment: благодарю, работает